# MapBox: MGLineStyleLayer drawn over Annotations

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mglmapview

I am trying to add Annotations and MGLineStyleLayer to the mapView. I am successfully adding them but the LineLayer is drawn above the annotations. I want the annotations to be drawn over the line layers. Here is my implementation

```
 /*This is where i am adding the markers*/
    func createMapPoints(points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D], dashed: Bool = false) {
        var waypointType: MapAnnotationEnum = .waypointAnnotation
        if dashed {
            waypointType = .offsetWaypoint
        }
        addLineLabel(points: points, width: 7, color: UIColor.white, dashed: dashed)
        for point in points {
            _ = addAnnotationLabel(location: point, title: "WP", type: waypointType)
        }
    }

    func addAnnotationLabel(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, type: MapAnnotationEnum) -> CustomMapGLAnnotaion {
        let annotation = CustomMapGLAnnotaion()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = title
        annotation.annotationType = type
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        return annotation
    }

    func addLineLabel(points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D], width: CGFloat, color: UIColor, dashed: Bool = false) {
        let polyline = CustomMapGLPolyline(coordinates: points, count: UInt(points.count))
        polyline.width = width
        polyline.color = color
        shapeCount += 1
        if dashed {
            polyline.title = "dashed"
            addDashedLine(polyline: polyline)
        } else {
            polyline.title = "0"
            addCasingLine(polyline: polyline)
        }
            print("Last Execution Point 3")
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(polyline)
    }

    func addCasingLine(polyline: MGLPolyline) {
        guard let style = self.mapView.style else { return }

        let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "line\(shapeCount)", shape: polyline, options: nil)
        style.addSource(source)

        style.layer(withIdentifier: )
        let lineLayer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "line-layer\(shapeCount)", source: source)
        lineLayer.lineJoin = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "round")
        lineLayer.lineCap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "round")
        lineLayer.lineColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: #colorLiteral(red: 0.1254901961, green: 0.4901960784, blue: 0.9137254902, alpha: 1))
        lineLayer.lineOpacity = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 1)
        lineLayer.lineWidth = NSExpression(format: "mgl_interpolate:withCurveType:parameters:stops:($zoomLevel, 'linear', nil, %@)", [14: 4, 18: 4])
        style.addLayer(lineLayer)
    }

    func addDashedLine(polyline: MGLPolyline) {
        guard let style = self.mapView.style else { return }
        let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "line\(shapeCount)", shape: polyline, options: nil)
        style.addSource(source)
        let dashedLayer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "polyline-dash\(shapeCount)", source: source)
        dashedLayer.lineJoin = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "round")
        dashedLayer.lineCap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "round")
        dashedLayer.lineColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9411764706, green: 0.3764705882, blue: 0.1921568627, alpha: 1))
        dashedLayer.lineOpacity = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 1)
        dashedLayer.lineWidth = NSExpression(format: "mgl_interpolate:withCurveType:parameters:stops:($zoomLevel, 'linear', nil, %@)", [14: 4, 18: 4])
        dashedLayer.lineDashPattern = NSExpression(forConstantValue: [0, 1.5])
        style.addLayer(dashedLayer)
    }
```

This is the definition of the two custom classes

```
  class CustomMapGLAnnotaion: MGLPointAnnotation {

    var annotationType: MapAnnotationEnum?
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    }

   class CustomMapGLPolyline: MGLPolyline {

    var width: CGFloat?
    var color: UIColor?
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
  }
```

Where am i going wrong? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For someone looking for an answer in the future!

Since `MGLAnnotationView` inherits from a `UIView` object. We can decide the ordering of the annotation feature simply by setting its `zIndex` property.

According to https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/overview/markers-and-annotations/